# PowerShell on remote target shows incomplete verbose logs

Tags: powershell, logging, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, verbose

I wrote the PowerShell script to run the SQL scripts on target database server using RoundhousE.

Example code in PowerShell script:

```
$outsideTransactionDir = (Join-Path $migrateDir "OutsideTransaction")
Write-Host $(Get-Item $outsideTransactionDir).FullName
if ((Test-Path $outsideTransactionDir) -eq $true)
{
    Write-Verbose "Running RoundhousE (Outside Transaction)" -Verbose
    Write-Host "Running RoundhousE (Outside Transaction)"
    ExecuteRoundhousE $(Get-Item $outsideTransactionDir).FullName $([String]::Format('-cs "{0}" -ni -ct 500 -rb "runBeforeUp" –-debug --env PROD --vf "db_version.xml" {1}', $settings.roundhouse.connectionstring, $r))
}
Write-Verbose "Running RoundhousE" -Verbose
Write-Host "Running RoundhousE"
ExecuteRoundhousE $(Get-Item $migrateDir).FullName $([String]::Format('-cs "{0}" --trx -ni -ct 500 -rb "runBeforeUp" -sp "StoredProcedure" -fu "UserDefinedFunction" -vw "View" -ix "Index" –-debug --env PROD --vf "db_version.xml" {1}', $settings.roundhouse.connectionstring, $r))
```

After executing the above lines of code through the Run PowerShell on Target Server task at VSTS release. Internally one text file will be created in specified server, it contains logs (changes) related to database SQL scripts execution, and also same logs will be displayed in VSTS release logs under specified task. But the issue is total logs will not be displayed In VSTS release logs only few logs will be displayed in VSTS release logs.

Comment: What's the output result if you call that ps script manually on your local machine? (Invoke-Command) https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-invoke-command-to-run-scripts-on-remote-computers/

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I am getting nearly 3000 lines of logs and at the end it shows the success message. but in VSTS release logs I am only getting half of the logs.

Comment: Do you mean call that script through Invoke-Command manually gets nearly 3000 lines of log? Try to add system.debug variable to release and set to true, then create a release and check the result.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I already tried by adding sytem.debug is true in VSTS release definition variables section. but I am getting the half of the logs.

Comment: Do you check Run PowerShell In Parallel option? If not, try to call Invoke-Command to run that script during release through PowerShell task, otherwise, call Start-Job. The source code of PowerShell on remote machine: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachines/PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, I already checked option as Run PowerShell in Parallel under Advanced Options of PowerShell on Target Machines VSTS task.

Comment: Try to call Invoke-Command through PowerShell task to run that script.